# Simple SELECT QUERY WITH Equal or Not EqualTo a Value

Tags: sql, t-sql

Let say I have this table,

```
A    B
-------
1    A
2    C
3    A
4    NULL
5    B
6    A
```

I have only a single parameter in stored procedure. I need to pass a single parameter `@param`. I need to select all rows equal to `A` or select all rows not equal to `A`. I have only a single parameter `@param`. If  `@param` = 'A' select all rows with A and If  `@param` <> 'A' select all rows with not equal to A.

**Edit:**

Here is 1 approach I have found. **Not sure** which approach is **best one**.

```
DECLARE @Param VARCHAR(5)='NOt A'

DECLARE @tbl TABLE(A INT,B VARCHAR(5))

INSERT INTO @tbl(A,B)
VALUES
    (1,'A'),
    (2,'C'),
    (3,'A'),
    (4,NULL),
    (5,'B'),
    (6,'A')

SELECT  * 
FROM    @tbl 
WHERE 1 = 
        (
            CASE    WHEN @param = 'A' 
                    THEN 
                    (
                        CASE WHEN B = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
                    ) 
                    ELSE 
                    (
                        CASE WHEN (B IS NULL OR B <> 'A') THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
                    ) 
                    END
        )
```

Comment: @marc_s, passing from an application. application is only passing A or not A

Comment: Selecting all rows equal to 'A' or not equal to 'A' would result in selecting all rows. Is that really what you are looking for?

Comment: @TPete, when application pass A then I need to select all rows with A and vice versa

Comment: @TPete I think he means as separate operations.

Comment: @user960567 This is confusing because you have a column named A but then there are rows in the B column with a value of A.  You're saying you need to match "A" so my first thought would be that you want all rows where the value in column B are equal to 'A', in which case you wouldn't even need a parameter.  I think the answer to your question is really simple if you can try to communicate just a little more carefully.

Comment: @BrandonMoore, see below answer of marc.

Comment: @user960567 Glad he could help you.  Don't forget to mark as answer if it was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly, you basically want to select all rows equal to `A` if the value of `@param` is indeed `A` - and all other rows if it's not `A` ??

Something like:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SelectRows @Param CHAR(1)
 AS 
 BEGIN
   IF @Param = 'A' THEN

     SELECT A, B
     FROM dbo.YourTable
     WHERE B = 'A'

   ELSE

     SELECT A, B
     FROM dbo.YourTable
     WHERE B <> 'A' OR B IS NULL

 END
```

Comment: Is this not possible with one query? With CASE etc

Comment: @user960567: I don't think so, since you once want to select based on **equality** - the other time on **inequality** - those aren't just different values, those are different conditions. `CASE` is great if you have a limited number of different **values** to pick from...

Comment: Just don't forget that the second query isn't going to pick up null values.  You will need to add 'or B is null' to the where clause if you want those records to.

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure you could use some trickery with case statements in the where clause to make it one statement but it wouldn't be worth the trouble and the next person to read it would have no clue what you're doing.

Comment: I got my answer using, select ...... where 1 = (CASE WHEN  @param = 'A' THEN (CASE WHEN B = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) ELSE (CASE WHEN (B IS NULL OR B <> 'A') THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) END)

Comment: @user960567: and that's clearer and easier to understand, and thus more maintanable!?!???!?

Comment: Your approach is not more maintanable. If I need to change the query then I need change this at 2 place.

Comment: @user960567: I still find this "solution" overly complicated - imagine you set this project aside and in a year, you have to come back and change something at it. Are you going to be able to understand **right away** what that query does?? I couldn't... Yes, my approach uses two separate queries - but they're **so dead simple** that it's totally obvious what they do - so maintaining them just just soooo much easier than your solution. Why are you so keen on having just one query??

Comment: The fact is that duplicating the SQl is very unmaintainable for me. Imagine(Let's say) I have 10 sql queries in a SP. Then it's mean I have to write and maintain this 20 times. BTW, I also like your approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The approach suggested by **marc_s** is the clearest to follow and easiest to maintain and for the query to be optimised.
If you insist on doing it in a single statement, you can do something like the following:

```
select A, B
from @tbl  
where ((@Param='A') and (B='A'))
   or ((@Param<>'A') and ((B<>'A') or (B is null)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this. Pls try to modify this query, you may get the result.

```
  SELECT A, B
         FROM dbo.YourTable
         WHERE B IN (CASE WHEN @Param='A' THEN 'A' ELSE
                        (SELECT B FROM yourTable where B<>'A' OR B IS NULL) END)
```

Comment: I have already tried something like B = (CASE WHEN @Param='A' THEN 'A' ELSE B END). But here is null issue

Comment: Thanks. I am going with the approach somthing like similar. see updated question.

Comment: I think your answer may work fine, but it is a little bit confusing. The problem will happen when you or someone else check this query after a long time , then this kind of approach may lead to time consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

First some test data:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(A INT,B VARCHAR(5))

INSERT INTO @tbl(A,B)
VALUES
    (1,'A'),
    (2,'C'),
    (3,'A'),
    (4,NULL),
    (5,'B'),
    (6,'A')
```

Then the query like this:

```
DECLARE @Param VARCHAR(5)='A'

SELECT
    *
FROM
    @tbl AS tbl
WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            @tbl AS tbl2
        WHERE
            @Param='A'
            AND tbl2.B=@Param
            AND tbl.A=tbl2.A
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            @tbl AS tbl3
        WHERE
            (NOT @Param='A' OR @Param IS NULL)
            AND (tbl.B<>'A' OR tbl.B IS NULL)
            AND tbl.A=tbl3.A
    )
```

Comment: It's more complex than marc's approach

Comment: You want it one one query.. Right? Then it might be a little bit more complex